# How to change pgcli text in query

Tags: postgresql

[image]

How can I change the red text `INSTANT` color in pgcli. It looks so dark and error-like

I tried edit `~/.config/pgcli/config` but do not found this name

Comment: Ok, I will accept my own answer after 20 hours. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** edit `syntax_style` in `~/.config/pgcli/config`